# FullCalendar addEventSource show double data?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am having problem with duplicate display of fetched events. I have a drop down list of users. When I select user, I first remove source, and then add new one. But when I change day, it shows events from both sources.

first, I create default view with default source:

```
var source1 = {  
           url: 'json-events.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
              start: $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('getView').start,
              end: $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('getView').end       
          }
         }
```

This is used to get initial events:

```
$('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
      source1
    ]
```

And then, to make changes after selected drop down list user:

```
$("select.getUser").change(function(){
    var userid=$('select.getUser :selected').val();
    $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources', source1);
    $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    var source2={
        url: 'json-events.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            start: $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('getView').start,
            end: $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('getView').end,
            userid : userid
        }
    };
    $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source2 );
})
```

The problem is when I change day or month or week, I get multiple POST request to server, showing events for each of the users, I selected. For example, if I select user1, the events are shown correctly, then I select user2, and again, the events are OK. But if I now change the day, I will get shown events from both user1 and user2 (I get 2 POST requests to server)

Comment: Instead of prefixing the question title with "SOLVED", you should move the solution to a new answer and then accept it. That way, other users can quickly see that the question has an accepted answer (and the question won't show up in the "Unanswered" category).

Comment: Sorry. It is my first post...  I can't answer right now - there is 8 hour limit to answer your own question - unless you have over 100 reputations, which I don't.

Comment: No problem, just set a reminder and come back in a couple of hours then. People will appreciate it. And welcome to SO!